# Does reassigning variables in a C++ function increase computational cost of executing the function?

Tags: c++, compilation, type-conversion, compiler-construction

Consider the following function:

```
void doMath(const std::vector<double> &v)
{
  double a = v[0];
  double b = v[1];
  double c = v[2];
  double d = v[3];
  double e = v[4];
  double f = v[5];

  //do math
}
```

If I have complex equations, often, changing the names of the variables make typing the equations much easier (e.g., avoiding typos, faster typing, more readable).

- I know the computational cost is minor, but is there **any** additional computation cost in contrast to using e.g., v[0] in operations instead of a = v[0]? For example, does the compiler know the assignment isn't necessary and optimize this during compilation?
- Does the data type make a difference? I imagine for more complex data types, yes it does (right?). For example, if the input is `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`, and I create `std::vector<double>` and reassign each element of the vector of vectors to separate vectors, would the compiler optimize this?

Comment: Can you share _why_ you are making copies of these values?  Is it to give them better-looking names?  If that's the case, make them references.

Comment: If you used a reference, then more then likely there will be no additional cost.

Comment: @DrewDormann Yes. The only reason is to give the element names.

Comment: You don't need to make runtime copies to do that.  `double &a =` or `double const& a =`.  The purpose of a reference is to create an alias to an existing value.

Comment: As an alternative to reference variables, you could use enumeration names for the indexes and use the vector directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a good idea. Thanks! However, I still feel just creating different variable make the code look more readable since I wouldn't have to use brackets, etc... (even if not THAT much more readable)

Comment: If `std::array` were used instead of `std::vector`, you could use structured bindings: `const auto& [a, b, c, ...] = v;`.

Comment: To actually answer the question: From the given examples, it can not be be said if there are additional costs, because the optimizer might do whatever it sees fit with the multiple copies eliminating some or all assignments anyway. In unoptimized code it obviously creates a lot of overhead, as all the values will be copied to it's own memory location.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is:  **profile** your optimized code, and compare the profiles of the two routines.  Read the generated assembly.  For performance critical code, help the optimizer by writing the code that panders to the optimizer (at the cost of making the code less legible & maintainable) — keep the straightforward suboptimal implementation as a reference implementation (also useful for integration testing to ensure parity).  All the forementioned analysis needs to be redone for every platform, and possibly for newer compilers that implement new powerful optimizations.

Comment: Problem is that your example has been stripped from important context. Note that in `C` and `C++` ["As If rule"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) has great impact on generated code. Compiler is able to do lots of cool stuff and drop variables which are not needed for final result. So your stripped example compiler can reduce to empty function (there are no visible results of execution). From my perspective question looks like beginner concern for unimportant details (since beginner do not know yet what is important yet).

Comment: @MarekR In my application, the cost of creating these additional variables for readability is so insignificant that it does not matter. However, I do this often, and I am curious under what scenario this could make a difference (even if the scenario is extreme).

Comment: Reasoning about performance on such low level is extremely hard. Compiler is able to do lots of wonders and sometimes fails in unexpected places. There are many nice talks form Matt Godbolt ([example](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)) where he shows this. So when you are checking performance there are 4 rules: measure, measure, measure, check assembly (to be sure that you are measure right thing). Last one is needed since "As If Rule" can strip code under test if you are not careful when writing performance test.

Answer (score 1):

No, not in general.  It could change the behavior of the function.

```
double a = v[0];
double b = v[1];
double c = v[2];
double d = v[3];
double e = v[4];
double f = v[5];
```

each of `a` through `f` is a copy of the state of the `v[i]` at the time the copy was made.  This copy doesn't have to be made, but the compiler has to guarantee that *if the `v[i]` changes* after that point, that change is not reflected in the state of the `a` through `f` variable.

C++ compilers use techniques like "static single assignment" to break your code down before optimizing it.  I mean, if you do this:

```
double a = v[0];
a = a + v[1];
```

a compiler might very well have *two names* for `a`.

```
double a' = v[0];
double a'' = a' + v[1];
```

here, each named value is assigned to only once.  It then unravels your code to work with this "immutable" versions of your local variables.

This doesn't work with values passed by reference or pointer.  There, the compiler has to either assume the reference/pointer is followed each time, or it has to prove that the indirection results in the exact same value at two adjacent lines.

```
double a = v[0];
double b = v[0];
```

the compiler is likely to be able to prove that `a` and `b` have the same value.  So it can skip reading from the reference `v` and from its internal pointer to the buffer twice.

```
double a = v[0];
some_function_pointer();
double b = v[0];
```

in this case, the compiler *cannot prove* that `a` and `b` are the same value unless it works out what the `some_function_pointer` function does.  Lacking that ability, it must independently calculate `a` and `b`.

When you do

```
double a = v[0];
double b = v[1];
double c = v[2];
double d = v[3];
double e = v[4];
double f = v[5];
```

you "lock" the values of the vector you are reading, taking a single snapshot.  So code afterwards that uses `a` through `f` may generate different assembly than code that uses `v[0]` through `v[5]`, only because it is easier for the compiler to prove the vector or its contents was not modified.

```
double const& a = v[0];
double const& b = v[1];
double const& c = v[2];
double const& d = v[3];
double const& e = v[4];
double const& f = v[5];
```

this ends up being a bit closer to using `v[0]` at point of use.  Here, changes to the vector's buffer should be reflected in `a` through `f`, but changes in the vector itself should not be (!).

While you passed the vector by `const&`, that just promises you won't modify `v` without a `const_cast`, it does not promise the vector will not be modified while you are running.  Anyone with a reference to the vector that isn't `const` can do so while you are running (say, you call a callback, or a system function, or anything the compiler cannot inline) is free to have modified the vector or its buffer.

---

As for more complex data types, a copy of a `double` is a noop unless the copy is modified differently than the source.

A copy of a `vector<double>` is *not* a noop in practice.  A copy of a `vector<double>` requests an allocation of a new buffer.

A compiler is free to notice that both the copy and the source is used only in an immutable manner and eliminate it, but that elimination is much harder than eliminating a mere `double`.  And if it does occur, the copy is more expensive.

A copy of a `double` is done every time you add doubles, in order to put it into a register.  So a single "needless" copy isn't a real cost; this copy can be the same copy as the one you do when you add it to another number, as compilers are great at eliminating duplicates like this.

A copy of a `vector` isn't done when you do most operations on it.  So a needless copy can have significant performance effects.

---

The elimination of the extra `double`s is a matter of "as-if" optimization.  The extra doubles really exist in the abstract machine that C++ specifies the behaviour of.

But doubles don't have much in the way of side effects to their existence.  As C++ specifies the behaviour of the abstract machine and only requires the concrete machine code it runs be consistent with it, removing things that exist in the abstract machine is perfectly legal!  So long as it behaves as-if they existed (up to undefined behaviour).

The same would be true of temporary vectors.  Except vectors have complex side effects in their existence, as they do things like allocate memory.  Modern C++ compilers are free to eliminate needless memory allocation, but it is harder than eliminating a mere 64 bit flat value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Very informative!

Answer (score 0):

Well no, but sometimes yes

On the one hand, assigning variables can be an expensive operation (we can mention copying std::string when not needed), and on the other hand, you want to have a nice, readable code. The fact is that your question does not have the correct answer. A lot depends on the specific task. In [some cases](https://godbolt.org/z/ovxefe6Ed), the optimizer may think to optimize redundant copying, in [some](https://godbolt.org/z/38z45vj3r) redundant copying will exist after optimization. Some say that in this case you can use the references, but also no one (or correct me) does not guarantee that they will not perform unnecessary operations.

So In some cases there will be no difference, but you can't be sure before writing the code.

The **main** advice I can give you is to MEASURE the execution time of your code after each optimization and remember that **Premature optimization is the root of all evil**